# How can we know number of active links of odoo Server .?

Tags: server, odoo, odoo-10

I am running odoo server using odoo service file:

```
/etc/init.d/odoo start
```

But when I need to `stop` or `restart` the server, I need to ask everyone that if they are using that server or not.

So my questions is , Is there any way that I can know number of users or links using that particular server.

If there is a way then I can directly `stop/restart` server without asking anyone , by only check from active links .

Comment: ! have you found any correct solution/answer?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get know the active users in odoo.

In older version like 6.1 they had field login_datetime but on later versions they store only "login_date".

you can only do is check openerp user active in the database and if not then restart/stop server.